# Automatic curve fitting in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting

Is there any package that automatically fits a curve using many simple models?
By simple models I mean:

- ax+b
- ax^2+bx+c
- a*log(x) + b
- a*x^n+b
- ax/(1+bx)
- ax^n/(1+bx^n)
- ...

The best would be to have a function that takes two vector parameters X and Y and returns a list of fitted simple models with their SSE.

Comment: @Roland: To find best nonlinear transformation in linear regression. I like to make a categorical variable (decils for example) from continuous variables and then look at the plot of parameters for each decil Vs average value in each decil. That helps to find nonlinear transformation of a variable. I would like to speed up this process a bit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this.  `rhs` is a character vector of right sides and `x` and `y` are the data.  It constructs the formula `fo` for each and then extracts the parameters and sets each to 1 for the starting value.  Finally it runs `nls` and returns the SSEs sorted so that the result is a vector of SSE's named via the right hand sides.  If `verbose=TRUE` (which it is by default) then it also displays the output from each fit.

```
sse <- function(rhs, x, y) sort(sapply(rhs, function(rhs, x, y, verbose = TRUE) {
    fo <- as.formula(paste("y", rhs, sep = "~"))
    nms <- setdiff(all.vars(fo), c("x", "y"))
    start <- as.list(setNames(rep(1, length(nms)), nms))
    fm <- nls(fo, data.frame(x, y), start = start)
    if (verbose) { print(fm); cat("---\n") }
    deviance(fm)
}, x = x, y = y))

## test

set.seed(123)
x <- 1:10
y <- rnorm(10, x)

# modify to suit
rhs <- c("a*x+b", "a*x*x+b*x+c")

sse(rhs, x, y)
```

Comment: Funny outcome, the 2nd order polynomial always fits the best of first four models using multiple rnorm datasets.  I assume this is because rnorm is only pseudorandom.  But why it would be best approximated by a 2nd order polynomial every time is odd...

Comment: Three parameters will fit better than two.  You can use AIC if you want to penalize more parameters or use SSE but just compare models with the same number of parameters.

Comment: Thanks for showing how to create such functions. I was hoping that it already exists, because I can think about 30 simple models off the top of my head which means that there is probably more than 100 hundred such models.

@ G. Grothendieck: Do You think that nls will give better results that nlminb?

Comment: `nls` is specialized for nonlinear least squares whereas `nlminb` is for a general objective so one would normally try `nls` for this type of problem first.

Answer (score 3):

You could also look at packages providing functions to evaluate fractional polynomials. So far, these appear to be `mboost` (with the function `FP`) and `mfp` (with the function `mfp`). Although I haven't tried the packages, the theory behind them fits what you're after.

The `mfp` package was described in [R-News](http://CRAN.R-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2005-2.pdf) in 2005.

Two references that might be of interest are

Royston P, Altman D (1994) Regression using fractional polynomials of continuous covariates. Appl Stat. 3: 429–467.

Sauerbrei W, Royston P (1999) Building multivariable prognostic and diagnostic models: transformation of the predictors by using fractional polynomials. Journal of the Royal Statistical Society (Series A) 162: 71–94.

Comment: Thanks, I've never heard about fractional polynomials. I will definetelly read about it!

Answer (score 1):

You can fit a Regression Splines and find a good fit by manually adjusting the degrees of freedom a few times.  Try the following function:

```
spline.fit <- function(x, y, df=5) {
  ## INPUT: x, y are two vectors (predictor and response);
  ##        df is the number of spline basis.  Increase "df" to fit more adaptively to the data.
  require(splines) # available as default R Package.
  bx <- bs(x, df)  # B-spline basis matrix as New Predictors (dimension is "length(x)" by "df")
  f <- lm(y ~ bx)  # Linear Regression on Spline Basis (that is, "df" number of new predictors)
  fy <- fitted(f)  # Fitted Response
  plot(x, y); lines(x, fy, col="blue", lwd=2) # Make a plot to show the fit.
  invisible(list(x=bx, y=fy, f=f))    # Return the Basis (new predictors), Fitted Y, Regression
}

if (F) {                                # Unit Test
  spline.fit(1:100, rnorm(100))
  spline.fit(1:100, rnorm(100), df=20)
}
```